# How to make 1-day lasting certificate?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I need a 1-day-last certificate to sign an Android test app. IntelliJ signed APK creator (Export Signed Android Package option) does not allow to create certificate with validity less than 1 year. And I know that people do create certificate that are valid for a couple of days.

How should I create a certificate that lasts for a couple of days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create it manually by using keytool (comes with jdk), however android market requires certificate that is valid atlease till 2033.

Excerpt from http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

If you plan to publish your application(s) on Android Market, the key you use to sign the application(s) must have a validity period ending after 22 October 2033. The Market server enforces this requirement to ensure that users can seamlessly upgrade Market applications when new versions are available.

Comment: I now about publishing. I have published apps before :). I just need a way to create certificate for demo apps. Any way to do it in IntelliJ? I have used `keytool` before but the IntelliJ's tool is way faster and less cumbersome.